# PayPal Website Payments Pro - Payment Declined

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-payments-pro

Setting up PayPal Website Payments Pro on Magento 2, I always see the error "Your payment has been declined. Please try again." when placing a credit card order. There's no exception information in any of the logs.

I suppose something is configured incorrectly with the PayPal settings. The [documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payments-pro.html) (see the note that outside US this is called PayPal Website Payments Pro) says, under Setting Up PayPal Payments Pro > Step 3 > 1 > b:

> Enter **one** of the following credentials that you use to log in to your PayPal merchant account

This however seems to be inaccurate because Magento won't allow the payment method to be activated unless ALL 3 fields are filled in.

So, I've entered:

- Partner: PayPal
- Vendor: My paypal login email address
- User: ??

For the user, the documentation says that I should enter:

> The ID of an additional user who is set up on your PayPal account.

There is only one user for this account, so I don't know what to put in this field. I've tried all the following with the same "declined" result:

- My PayPal login email
- My Merchant account Id

Am I supposed to enter my own user id? If so, how do I find out what it is - there is nothing with a name like that in my PayPal account.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my paypal integration's. I suggest you to take paypal support for this. I just got it fixed with paypal guy. Also sometimes issues occur due to paypal configurations settings. So, the best solution I suggest you to take support from paypal.